# Calling dll function but file cannot be written when application is open

Tags: visual-c++, dll, function

I have a function in a dll that involves reading and writing a file.

I am calling the dll function in a test application but the file could not be written when the application is still open. I always need to close the test application first before the file could be successfully written.

What do I have to do to fix this?

I am calling the function repeatedly in a loop. When there are multiple items needed to to processed using that function, the application crashes. It works fine when only one item is processed. What can I do?

**Note:** my dll is actually an `.exe` that I converted to dll.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be the file is already open. Is your code doing a file open and then leaving the file open?

Check the code to make sure there is a matching file close for every file open.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file with the right sharing permissions? What API are you using to open the file?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a different file name when you call the function from your test code.  If possible, modify the dll to accept a filename.

If not, make sure you open the file in shared mode.